# watir phantomjs in ruby facing issue after initialization in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, watir-webdriver

I am trying to use watir with phantomJS.  Itt is working fine, but I am not able to use it in rails console after successfully executing:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
```

I am not able to type properly and keystrokes are dropping randomly. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your input keystrokes aren't being displayed? Can you be more specific about the issue?

Comment: yeah, keystrokes are not being displayed properly, if i press a key then it might or might not display, i have to press it multiple times.